# Does return statement create a temporary object for functions returning by value?

Tags: c++, c++11

As I am learning C++11 rvalue references and move semantics, I start to feel confused about exactly how function returns a value to initialize a variable. Look at the following example:

```
Widget makeWidget()
{
    Widget w;
    …
    return w;
}
Widget w1 = makeWidget();
```

Here I assume no RVO (i.e., the compile won't elide copy/move). When executing the return statement `return w;`, does the function:

**1)** copy initialize a temporary object, whose value becomes the function's return value, in a well known location (some fixed register or memory location that caller knows)? Then caller fetches this object to copy initialize `w1`? Or

**2)** the function gets the caller-passed memory location of `w1` and the function's automatic variable `w` is used to copy initialize `w1`? (Is this some sort of RVO already? Or some sort of inline function behavior? Or it is a possible calling convention?)

If it is the first case, and return creates a temporary, there would be two copy constructor calls, one creating the temporary, one creating `w1`. If it is the second case, there would be only one copy constructor call to create `w1`.

Now assume we have RVO. Then if the behavior of return is case **1)**, then compiler can elide the copy construction of the temporary, by constructing `w` directly in the well known location for return value. If return behaves like case **2)**, then RVO, in this case, can even create automatic variable `w` directly in the memory location allocated for `w1`. Is my understanding for RVO correct?

---

Now let me add move semantics in. Assume again, there is no RVO, and look at the following example:

```
Widget makeWidget()
{
    Widget w;
    …
    return std::move(w);
}
Widget w1 = makeWidget();
```

Now again for the two cases above:

**1)** do I expect two moves: first move comes from initializing the temp `Widget` object with expression `std::move(w)`; second move comes from initializing `w1` with the temp `Widget` which is a rvalue? OR

**2)** there is only one move: initializing `w1` with the expression `std::move(w)` ?

---

Final question: does the return behavior depend on whether it returns a POD type or a class type?

Comment: The calling convention with most compilers is, the caller passes in a pointer to raw space into which the function constructs its return value. At the least efficient (no RVO at all), a temporary is copy-constructed from `w` in that space, and then `w1` is copy-constructed from that temporary. Most compilers would elide one or both of these copies - the latter by passing the space allocated for `w1` to the function so the return value is constructed directly into `w1`; the former by making `w` an alias for that same space, in effect making `w` and `w1` refer to the same object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) copy initialize a temporary object, whose value becomes the
>   function's return value, in a well known location (some fixed register
>   or memory location that caller knows)? Then caller fetches this object
>   to copy initialize w1?

Roughly this. Usually, the caller allocates the necessary stack space to hold the return value and pass a pointer to it as a hidden argument.

Note that both copy-initializations are actually moves.

> then compiler can elide the [...] construction of the temporary, by
>   constructing `w` directly in the well known location for return value.

Right (but it's a move). And it can further elide the construction of `w1` by passing its address as the location at which the return value should be constructed.

> ```
> Widget makeWidget()
> {
>     Widget w;
>     …
>     return std::move(w);
> }
> Widget w1 = makeWidget();
> ```

This is one non-elidable move (from `std::move(w)` to the temporary return value) and one elidable move (from the temporary return value to `w1`).

> does the return behavior depend on whether it returns a POD type or a
>   class type?

It can. Depending on the platform ABI, some small POD types may be returned in registers.