# Why is the copy constructor called twice?

Tags: c++

In the following code, the copy constructor is being called twice, why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    int X;
public:
    A() {
        cout << "Simple Constructor" << endl;
    }
    A(int b) :X(b) {
        cout << "Constructor " << X << endl;
    }
    A(const A& obj) :X(obj.X) {
        cout << "Copy Constructor " << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "Destructor " << X << endl;
    }
};
A fun(A obj) {
    cout << "Fun" << endl;
    return obj;
}
int main() {
    A obj(10);
    obj = fun(obj); // here is confusion
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor 10
Copy Constructor
Fun
Copy Constructor
Destructor 10
Destructor 10
End
Destructor 10
```

I'm thinking maybe the second copy constructor is being called due to temporary object.

Comment: In `fun()` you take a copy and return a copy, so why you wonder?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ returning object copied to temporary object? and then function's object and temporary object destroy?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok but something compiler neglect the temporary object. and do not call copy constructor for temporary object.. can you clear me where compiler called the temporary object's copy constructor or destructor?

Comment: Compilers are allowed to eliminate the temporary copy if there's no side effect. `cout`  counts as side effect.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm thinking compiler should not call copy constructor for temporary object. It's just confusing why copy constructor & Destructor called for temporary object. have you any link that can clear my confusion?

Comment: It's called [_copy elision_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383639/conditions-for-copy-elision?s=1|5.6979), if you want to dig further.

Comment: There's the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409925/does-return-statement-create-a-temporary-object-for-functions-returning-by-value) asked very recently BTW.

Answer (score 4):

The first call of copy constructor is performed when you call fun(obj). You pass obj by value, so it is copied and the copy is used inside of the function.
Next copy is performed when you return obj in fun. It is also returned by value, so it is copied again.

I don't know what is your intent. If you want to modify the object in function, it would be better to pass it by reference and make function void:

```
void fun(A& obj) {
    cout << "Fun" << endl;
}
```

and just call

```
fun(obj);
```

This way you prevent both calls to copy constructor.

Edit:

If you wonder why Return Value Optimization is not performed, you should know that it is optional behavior, that is allowed for the compiler by the standard. First you should make sure that your compiler is allowed to optimise the code (eg. you don't use Debug Build) and then that it actually supports RVO. Finaly you should think if the optimization really makes sense in this case. Your object has only one int inside, so it has a size of the base type.
One thing to remember about optimization is that it CAN be performed but compiler is the one that decides, whether to perform it or not.

Comment: but 2nd copy, copied to temporary object?

Comment: It is copied from obj (in return statement) to temporary object, and then the default assignment operator is called (in obj = fun...) which takes const reference as an argument.